# How to connect to and keep the session alive using python requests

Tags: http, httprequest

I am trying to login to a site, and then view user details.

The API documentation from the site is:

```
LogOn : All Calls with JSON and return JSON type

post - https://www.bit2c.co.il/Account/LogOn  {UserName:'',Password:'',SecondFactor:[optional]} 
return true if OK , error list of strings if not

Balance - GET https://www.bit2c.co.il/Account/Balance
return UserBalance as JSON
```

I've tried connecting to the site using

```
import requests
session=requests.session()
session.auth = ("username", "pass")
session.post("https//www.bit2c.co.il/Account/Balance")
```

but i am getting response 200 and the response content is "you must login".

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What kind of _session_? What is on server-side?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of *session*? What is on server-side? Can you post the raw request/response pair(s)?

If PHP or ASP runs on server-side, you must capture the `Set-Cookie` header of the response to the login request, find the session cookie and in consequent requests you must set the `Cookie` header with the session cookie name and value captured previously.